# Xamarin the type 'CollectionView' was not found

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use a CollectionView in my Xamarin App. Here is the code in my MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HPlusSports"
             x:Class="HPlusSports.MainPage">

    <CollectionView>

    </CollectionView>

</ContentPage>
```

There is a squiggly under the text CollectionView with this error: "the type 'CollectionView' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built"
I've read that you have to put this line

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
```

in the MainActivity.cs file for Android and App.xaml.cs file for UWP before the init line (I don't have an iOS project). So I tried adding in those lines then building the project, but I still can't seem to use a CollectionView. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and have all the latest updates installed. I can't build my project if I try to use a CollectionView.

Comment: what version of Forms are you using?  Do you have the same version installed in all projects?

Comment: I don't know, how do I check that?

Comment: look at the version of the XF nuget package

Comment: version 3.4.0.1008975. It's the same in all projects.

Comment: CollectionView was introduced in 4.x

Comment: So you're saying I need to update Xamarin.Forms to v4 or newer in all my projects?

Comment: Yes.  If you want to use CollectionView then you have to install a version of XF that includes CollectionView.

Comment: @technoman23 Hi , have you solved this by updating XF to v4 ?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Seems to have done the trick!

Comment: @Jason if you want to post an answer I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CollectionView was introduced in Xamarin Forms 4.x.  You need to update your XF nuget packages

Comment: I updated to v4 but I get a new error now InvalidOperationException: The class, property, or method you are attempting to use ('VerifyCollectionViewFlagEnabled') is part of CollectionView; to use it, you must opt-in by calling Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental") before calling Forms.Init().
I did this in my .Android MainActivity.cs file but The error persists

Comment: the latest version of Forms should not require the flag any more.  If you can't upgrade to latest, check the docs to be sure you're enabling the flag correctly.

Comment: I updated to version 4.3 and the flag error went away. Looks like they introduced some additional support somewhere around there so you don't have to include that anymore. Thanks again!